# What's the point of nested resources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Say I have the prototypical blog app in Rails. I would have a Post model which has many Comments. My routes.rb might look like this:

```
resources :post do
    resources :comment
end
```

This means that for instance the edit path for a comment looks like this: `/post/21/comment/42/edit`.
It appears to make sense when we have a has many/belongs to relationship between two models.
However, once you notice that the id of the post is not really needed to find the comment (or even the post), it starts to make less sense.

To see what I mean, consider these two equivalent implementations of the edit action in the controller:

```
# Nested resource version
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    # ...
end
```

vs.

```
# Un-nested resource version
def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @post = @comment.post
    # ...
end
```

My question is: Is there a use case for this I haven't considered? Or are nested resources only good for making pretty URLs?

Comment: For editing/updating it doesn't make much sense, but for new comments it *does* make sense. E.g. `/posts/21/comments/new` tells the `CommentsController` that the new comment belongs to the post with id 21.

Comment: `Comment.find(params[:post_id])` will find you a comment that has the same ID as your post...

Comment: @Mischa True, but is it really worth it for that alone? I mean you could just as easily have a hidden field in your form with the post_id.

Comment: Rails actually recognises that nesting for edit/show is generally unnecessary and provides a `shallow: true` for nested routes which only generate the new, create and index as nested.

Comment: @KaptajnKold, some people may find this cleaner than adding a hidden field with `post_id`. As nmott mentions, for `index` it makes even more sense: `/posts/21/comments` lists all the comments belonging to post with id 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

Yes, it does make sense in some cases:

- Contrary to what is assumed in the question, it is not a given that the comment's id is sufficient to find the post it belongs to. The comment's id may only be one component of a *composite primary key* of which the post's id is the other component.
- Suppose the user mistypes the Comment's id, or maybe the more common scenario, that the user follows a link to a Comment that has been deleted. If the Post's id is present in the URL, the application has the option to present the user with a more helpful response than a generic 404 page, showing for example an index of all the Post's Comments with a message saying that the particular Comment that the user requested does not exist.
- The convention of RESTful URLs is that if the user removes the Comment id from the URL, they should be presented with an index page. If Comment is a sub resource of Post, this index page should only contain the Comments that belong to the same Post, but without the Post id present in the URL, this would not be possible.